# Connect Listener using REST?

Tags: rest, soap, docusignapi

Does connect support listeners written using REST or only SOAP?  By looking at the [DocuSign Connect Guide](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf) It seems that they are only supporting SOAP but wanted to make sure.

Comment: The SOAP Api that you are referring to in the Connect guide is for setting up your connect configuration in our Account.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "Written in Rest or SOAP".

Docusign connect follows the Webhook pattern

- After you configure your webhook (Connect) subscription, the DocuSign platform will initiate an HTTPS POST call to your application when a notification message is ready for your app.
- Your app must include a listener HTTPS URL that DocuSign can POST to

See this [link](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/) for more information

Also you are referring to Old documentation. Docusign has both Rest and SOAP apis. You can find documentation in Docusign [developer center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center).

---

Edit:
Here are implementations of listeners for Docusign connect in different languages

- [node.js](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-node)
- [python](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-python)
- [java](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-java)
- [c#](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp)
- [php](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-php)

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status

Comment: They do have both API flavors but it seems from what I read in the guide that the listener has to be written to accept messages via SOAP.

Comment: listener has nothing to do with SOAP. Its just an XML notification message that docusign sends to your listener Url. I have edited my answer to specify links to various implementatios of the listeners